# Start edit in cell c# + wpf with telerik library

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, cell, telerik-grid

I need to implementation auto start begin edit cell in the same row and next column, after click in previous column.

In begin my table, code works correctly. But in the last row and in penultimate column code doesn't work correctly, it begin start edit in the last row and in third column.

But after how I write value by myself, code start to work correctly. I use telerik framework.

Thank you for your responses!

```
c#
var element = sender as FrameworkElement;
        ConditionsRadGridView.CommitEdit();
        var parentCell = element.GetVisualParent<GridViewCell>();
        if (parentCell != null)
        {
            var index = ConditionsRadGridView.Columns.IndexOf(parentCell.Column);
            if (index != -1 && index < parentCell.ParentRow.Cells.Count)
            {
                var nextCell = parentCell.ParentRow.Cells[index] as GridViewCell;
                if (nextCell != null)
                {
                    ConditionsRadGridView.CurrentCellInfo = new GridViewCellInfo(nextCell);
                    ConditionsRadGridView.BeginEdit();
                }
            }
        }
```

part of wpf

```
    <telerik:RadGridView ValidatesOnDataErrors="InViewMode"                       
                     Name="ConditionsRadGridView"
                     Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                     Margin="6 3 6 6" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                     CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserInsertRows="False" ShowGroupPanel="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                     FrozenColumnCount="1"
                     CanUserFreezeColumns="False"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Conditions}" EnableColumnVirtualization="False"
                     RowStyle="{StaticResource ValidationFixStyle}"
                     SelectionMode="Extended"  
                     cal:Message.Attach="[Event PreviewKeyUp] = [Action ConditionsKeyUp($this.SelectedItems, $eventArgs)]">
        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource SelectedCellStyle}" Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.Station}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ConditionNameTemplateSelector}"/>
                <telerik:GridViewColumn IsVisible="{Binding IsHaveGroups}">
                <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Visibility="{Binding IsGroup, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSplitUp, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                  cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action IsSplitUpClick($datacontext)]" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewColumn>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.AffinityOperator}" ColumnGroupName="Affinity"
                                    DataMemberBinding="{Binding AffinityOperator, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True">
          <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:StationConditionViewModel}">
              <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <controls3:RadComboBox IsEnabled="{Binding IsRowEnabled}" SelectionChanged="StartEditNextCell"
                                       SelectedItem="{Binding AffinityOperator, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                       ItemsSource="{Binding Operators}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
          </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.AffinityValue}" ColumnGroupName="Affinity" IsReadOnlyBinding="{Binding AffinityIsReadOnly}"
                                     DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=AffinityValue}" TextAlignment="Right">
      <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:StationConditionViewModel}">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding AffinityValue, StringFormat={}{0:N2}}" Visibility="{Binding AffinityVisibility}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```